# Magento 2.2 : Static block call to every CMS Page

Tags: blocks, magento2.2, cms

How to call a static block call every cms page in Magento 2.2

Answer (score 4):

You need to override **cms_page_view.xml** layout file in your theme/module.

In that file, you need call static block over there with **static block id**:

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">static_block_id</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works for you as it can help others to identify solution easily.

Comment: @Sarvagya Correct, Please accept this as an answer if it's correct.